# Going to a specific page number in a GridView paging feature

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging

I am trying to implement GO TO page by allowing the user to enter page number in a text box and clicking a button texted as GO.

.aspx code is;

```
<asp:Label ID="lblGoToPage" runat="server" Text="Go To Page : "></asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtGoToPage" runat="server" Width="47px"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnGo" runat="server" Text="Go" OnClick="btnGo_Click" />
```

and .cs code is;

```
protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = Convert.ToInt16(txtGoToPage.Text);
        txtGoToPage.Text = "";
    }
```

These above lines of code are giving out but not the desired one. Cant figure out where I am going wrong. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rebind the grid after you change the page index.

```
protected void btnGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.PageIndex = Convert.ToInt16(txtGoToPage.Text) -1; //since PageIndex starts from 0 by default.
        txtGoToPage.Text = "";
        GridView1.DataBind()
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt help. Really appreciate it. Your solution worked like a charm. Only a little bit of editing done. Thank you heaps.